# is not able to run the selenium tests

Tags: selenium, testng

[TestNG] is not able to run the selenium tests.

This is my testng.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Regression1"   >
    <packages>
      <package name="com.example.tests" />
   </packages>
 </test>
</suite>
```

When I run run_testNG ant task, I am getting

```
Buildfile: build.xml
prepare:
compile:
run_test:
  [waitfor] Wait for proxy server launch
start-server:
run_testNG:
   [testng] [TestNG] Running:
   [testng]   /softwares/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/run_test/testng.xml
   [testng] 
   [testng] 
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] Suite1
   [testng] Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
   [testng] ===============================================
   [testng] 
stop-server:
[selenium-shutdown] Getting: http://localhost:4444/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
[selenium-shutdown] To: /softwares/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.3/run_test/result.txt
[selenium-shutdown] DGF Errors during shutdown are expected
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

It is not running any test. Please let me know what could be the issue. If you like, I can share my build.xml also.

Comment: Do you actually have a package named com.example.tests? If you do, please post a test class found in it.

Answer (score 1):

Could be due to multiple reasons:
1. Your code might not have methods which have @Test annotations
2. Package name could be wrong